# Cálculo em paralelo utilizando GeForce Cuda

Tags: c#, paralelismo, cuda

Tenho o seguinte método que calcula o valor de PI de forma serial:

```
        public static double CalculoPISerie()
        {
            double integral = 0;
            double h = 1.0 / NUMERO;

            for (int i = 0; i <= NUMERO; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0 || i == NUMERO)
                    integral += (4.0 / (1.0 + Math.Pow(i * h, 2)));
                else
                    integral += (2 * ((4.0 / (1.0 + Math.Pow(i * h, 2)))));
            }

            return integral * h / 2;
        }
```

Gostaria de fazer esse método de forma paralela utilizando CUDA da GeForce.
Como posso fazer ?

Comment: E só você usa uma thread

Comment: Como faço esse método com threads ?

Comment: você já instalou algum compilador para CUDA? Comece por aqui: http://www.nvidia.com/content/cuda/cuda-toolkit.html

Comment: Instalei tudo já. não sei agora como implementar esse método de forma paralela

Comment: Aqui a documentação threads http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__THREAD__DEPRECATED.html#group__CUDART__THREAD__DEPRECATED

Comment: Acredito que, além do CUDA Toolkit, você vai precisar de um *wrapper* para acessar o código não gerenciado a partir do `C#`. Uma opção de lib para isso: http://kunzmi.github.io/managedCuda/